# How can I submit a bug for Ubuntu installer?

Tags: system-installation, bug-reporting

How can I submit a bug for Ubuntu installer?
I see an error in Ubuntu 17.10 netboot installer but the netboot system does not have tools to create a bug on Launchpad.

Answer (score 1):

The Ubuntu community page on [Reporting Bugs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs) also includes details of how report bugs when offline or using a headless setup, using apport.

Comment: it is suitable for the installed system.
I have no installed system. Only installer which configured partition table and failed on "Install the base system" step.